# Internal method call - using loop iterate number of games

Tags: java, loops

Hi I am creating a piece of code similar the monty hall problem - where the user selects a door out of 3 doors and another door is selected at random. The program then gives the user the option to stick with their choice or swap to the selected at random door. I have the code below which is basically meant to test how many times a game will win by switching or sticking.

The playGame() method works fine - however i seem to be stuck on the if(true) section of the code. If i call the method with 100 as the parameter it prints out

Wins by sticking: 101
Wins by switching: 101

Can anyone point me to the correct direction to fix the code?

My issue seems to be that the if statement in the loops are always true (even though i have tested the playGame method which returns false/true).

My loop always seems to be true which means the number of numRunsStick/numRumsSwitch are always true and being added to.

Apologies as im a bit of a novice to coding at the minute

```
public boolean playGame(boolean isStick)
    {
        setUp();
        int contChoice = getContestantChoice();
        int switchChoice = findAlternativeDoor(contChoice);
        int choice;
    
        if (isStick)
        {
            choice = contChoice;
        }
        else
        {
            choice = switchChoice;
        }
    
        if (choice == doors.indexOf("car") +1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void test(int numGames)
    {
        int numRunsSwitch = 0;
        int numRumsStick = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= numGames; i++)
        {
            playGame(true);
            if (true)
            {
                numRumsStick++;
            }
        
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i <= numGames; i++)
        {
            playGame(false);
            if (true)
            {
                numRunsSwitch++;
            }
        }
    
        System.out.println("Wins by sticking: " +numRumsStick);
        System.out.println("Wins by switching: "+numRunsSwitch);
    }
```

Comment: if ( true ) { numRunsSwitch++; } -> seriously?

Comment: `if (true)` is **always** executed, making the entire condition totally pointless. What is the **real condition**, when **you** want the body executed?

Comment: Sorry, I want to first playGame with a parameter of (true), then the condition should be (if using playGame(true) returns true) then the code should run, otherwise iterate and play the game again

Comment: so, you would rather need a while loop compared to a for loop containing an if statement

Comment: Got it. I changed the loops to the below

for (int i = 0; i <= numRuns; i++)
        {
            if (playGame(true) == (true))
            {
                numRumsStick++;
            }
            
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= numRuns; i++)
        {
            if (playGame(false) == (true))
            {
                numRunsSwitch++;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of times sticking or switching led to winning the game, you need to check the outcome of the game. In the code that you have provided, the function `playGame` gives out the outcome of the game in terms of the return value `true` or `false`. `true` meaning you won the game, `false` meaning you lost the game.

Now, your strategy for counting is that you want to keep on "sticking" for 101 times and count how many times you won. For that the code should be

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= numGames; i++)
    {
        win = playGame(true);
        if (win == true)
        {
            numRumsStick++;
        }
    
    }
```

here we check the outcome of the game to see if we have really won. And if we have won, we increase the count. In your code, you were not checking this condition and increasing the count whether you won or lost and that is why you had the unexpected counts.

Similar steps are required to check for "switching"

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numGames; i++)
        {
            win = playGame(false);
            if (win == true)
            {
                numRunsSwitch++;
            }
        }
```

PS. If you originally intended to have the game play out for 100 times and not 101 times. You need to fix that in your `for` loop. A loop starting from `0` and going `<=100` means 0,1,2...100 i.e. a total 101 count. To make it 100, you should start the loop from `0` make the condition `<100` and that way the loop would go upto `99` making the total count 100. or you can start from `1` and go upto `<=100` and you would still have a total 100 count.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can combine the stay or switch selection in the same loop.
Here is another version of the game for comparison.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StaySwitchGame {

    static int getRandom(int limit) {
        return (int) (Math.random() * limit) + 1;
    }

    static Scanner dev = new Scanner(System.in);

    static boolean getIsSwitch() {
        System.out.print("Switch? Y/N : ");
        return (dev.next().charAt(0) == 'y');
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int TOTAL_RUN = 10; // total of tries
        final int DICE = 5;       // number of choices for random
        final int MATCH_NUM = 4;  // hit number
        
        int winStay = 0;
        int winSwitch = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_RUN; i++) {
            int choice = getRandom(DICE);              // first guess
            if( getIsSwitch() ) {
                if ( getRandom(DICE) == MATCH_NUM ) {  // second guess
                    winSwitch++;
                }
            } else {
                if ( choice == MATCH_NUM ) {
                    winStay++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Win by stick/stay : " + winStay + "/" + TOTAL_RUN);
        System.out.println("Win by switch : " + winSwitch + "/" + TOTAL_RUN);
    }
}
```